# What is written at the back of Half-Elf Monk Art Card (AFR)?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Regarding the card Half-Elf Monk Art Card (AFR): https://scryfall.com/card/aafr/28/half-elf-monk-half-elf-monk

What is the written at its back?

```
?? (??), Challenge ??
Armor Class ??, Hit Points ??
Speed ? ft.
Attacks ??
STR ? (+?)
DEX ? (+?)
CON ? (+?)
INT ? (+?)
WIS ? (+?)
CHA ? (+?)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This art card does not have a stat block on the back at all. It simply has the standard art card back, which basically just says:

> Half-Elf Monk ️ Zoltan Boros, 28/81

Adventures in the Forgotten Realms had two types of art cards, and only one type had stat blocks on the back. They are divided in two sections on Wizard's page for [Adventures in the Forgotten Realms Art Cards](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/card-image-gallery/adventures-forgotten-realms-art-cards-2021-07-12):

- The first section is **Art cards with stats**. These are all Forgotten Realms monsters and have stat blocks on the back. They run [collector numbers 1–27](https://scryfall.com/search?q=set%3Aaafr+cn%3E%3D1+cn%3C%3D27). You can hit the little “turn over” button on either site to view the back.
- The second section is named simply **Art cards**. These have no special treatment on the back, meaning no stat blocks. They have the standard art card back with the card name and artist attribution. These are collector numbers 28–81.

Half-Elf Monk is the very first card in the *second* group, and so has no stats at all. You can also see that in this photo which shows Adventures in the Forgotten Realms art cards from collector number 28 onwards:

[image: a photo of the backs of Adventures in the Forgotten Realms art cards 28 thru 81 showing a plain white back with Magic logo and artist attribution]